# Django - Auto populating Many-To-Many-Field relation

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, many-to-many

I am trying to make a form that auto populates a many-to-many relation for my user model. The goal is to have a submit button that adds the views instance object (the SingelWorkout object) to a many-to-many field relation within my user model.

The view accurately displays the correct object, and the form appears as intended within the template. I do not wish for the user to see the many-to-many field selection. Aside from the submit button, I am trying to have all logic to occur on the backend. How would I assign an object instance to a field within a form? Would this occur in the views.py or the forms.py?

Here is why my user model looks like:

```
class FitnessUser(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60)
    age_category = models.ForeignKey(
        AgeGroup,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    goal = models.IntegerField(default=1 ,choices=Purpose.choices)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    height = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    gender = models.ForeignKey(
        Gender,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    exercise_frequency = models.IntegerField(default=1 ,choices=Frequency.choices)
    template_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Workout_template,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True
        )
    completed_workouts = models.ManyToManyField(SingleWorkout)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', args=[self.id])
```

This is my form in forms.py:

```
class CustomWorkoutChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm):
        model = FitnessUser
        fields = ('completed_workouts',)
        exclude = ('completed_workouts',)
        UserChangeForm.password = None
```

This is how my view looks:

```
class WorkoutUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = SingleWorkout
    template_name = 'workout/daily_view.html'
    form_class = CustomWorkoutChangeForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("template")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(WorkoutUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['workout'] = SingleWorkout.objects.get(slug = self.kwargs['slug'])
        return context
```

My html template looks like this:

```
{{workout}}
<br>
workout:
<br>
{{ workout.exercise_1 }}
<br>
{{ workout.description_1 }}
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

Comment: I think you have to override the `save()` method of your `ModelForm`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution. I created a view that gets the instance object based on the objects url slug, and also gets the user by its pk. From there is adds the instance object to the users many to many field, then redirects back to the previous page.

New view created:

```
def update_workout_data(request, slug):   
    workout = SingleWorkout.objects.get(slug=slug)
    endUser = FitnessUser.objects.get(pk = request.user.pk)
    endUser.completed_workouts.add(workout)
    endUser.save()
    return redirect(reverse('daily', kwargs={'slug':workout.slug}))
```

Updated HTML appearance. I've also altered the html and its detail view so that the update link will redirect to a separate update view, depending on the need to add/remove the relation.

```
{% block content %}
Daily View
<br>
{{exercise}}
<br>
workout:
<br>
<br>
{% if exercise.name in workouts %}
<h5>Workout Already Completed</h5>
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'remove' slug=exercise.slug %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Reset</button>
</form>
{% else %}
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'update' slug=exercise.slug %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Complete</button>
</form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Updated Detail View

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(WorkoutDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = FitnessUser.objects.get(pk = self.request.user.pk)
        context['exercise'] = SingleWorkout.objects.get(slug = self.kwargs['slug'])
        context['workouts'] = {}
        for workout in user.completed_workouts.all():
            context['workouts'][workout.name] = workout
        return context
```